# Problem to load a UserControl inside XAML node

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, toolbar

I have a separated assembly where I defined several standard UserControls. Some of this are standard toolbars, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXX.ToolbarFullMaintenance"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
<ToolBar
    Style="{DynamicResource ToolbarMainStyle}"
>
/* MY BUTTONS */
</ToolBar>
</UserControl>
```

now, I would insert this toolbar inside a ToolBarTray on my window. I try to do this:

```
<ToolBarTray>
  <toolbars:ToolbarFullMaintenance
       Band="1"
       BandIndex="1"
       Name="mainToolbar" />
</ToolBarTray>
```

but don't work..."mainToolbar" is saw like a UserControl and not like a ToolBar.
How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made your `ToolBar` a child of a custom `UserControl` and thus `ToolBarTray` knows nothing about and embedded `ToolBar`. You can rectify your design by changing the base class of your `ToolbarFullMaintenance` to `ToolBar` instead of `UserControl` like so:

```
<ToolBar x:Class="XXX.ToolbarFullMaintenance"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Style="{DynamicResource ToolbarMainStyle}">

     /* MY BUTTONS */

</ToolBar>
```